# server 500 error python (visualstudio)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I'm developing a python app using Djgango and I'm getting the server 500 error. I believe my paths are set correctly, the python manage.py runserver returns that the server is running. When I look at developer tools on the page it says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (not found) http://localhost:64915/favicon.co" and "failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (internal server error) http://localhost:64915/."

I don't know what is going on? I'm new to Django coming from asp.net which runs without all the go around. can you help me? Here is my wsgi.py file code.

```
"""
WSGI config for SmartShopper project.

This module contains the WSGI application used by Django's development server
and any production WSGI deployments. It should expose a module-level variable
named ``application``. Django's ``runserver`` and ``runfcgi`` commands discover
this application via the ``WSGI_APPLICATION`` setting.

Usually you will have the standard Django WSGI application here, but it also
might make sense to replace the whole Django WSGI application with a custom one
that later delegates to the Django one. For example, you could introduce WSGI
middleware here, or combine a Django application with an application of another
framework.

"""
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "SmartShopper.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

# Apply WSGI middleware here.
# from helloworld.wsgi import HelloWorldApplication
# application = HelloWorldApplication(application)
```

here is my settings.py file code

```
"""
Django settings for SmartShopper project.
"""

from os import path
PROJECT_ROOT = path.dirname(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)))

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ALLOWED_HOSTS = (
    'localhost',
)

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

LOGIN_URL = '/login'

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static').replace('\\', '/')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'n(bd1f1c%e8=_xad02x5qtfn%wgwpi492e$8_erx+d)!tpeoim'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'SmartShopper.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'SmartShopper.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or
    # "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

# Specify the default test runner.
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
```

when running with debug = true it says I have an error in the view.py on line 19 - the render line. This is an autogenerated view by visual studio. I already had to change the url.py to reflect an upated django format. I wonder if you guys can help me spot the same here. here is my code for the views.py.

```
Definition of views.
"""

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.template import RequestContext
from datetime import datetime

def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )

def contact(request):
    """Renders the contact page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/contact.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'Contact',
            'message':'Your contact page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )

def about(request):
    """Renders the about page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/about.html',
        context_instance = RequestContext(request,
        {
            'title':'About',
            'message':'Your application description page.',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        })
    )
```

here is the traceback.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:64625/

Django Version: 1.10.2
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'app')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\GitHub\Capstone\SmartShopper\SmartShopper\app\views.py" in home
  19.             'year':datetime.now().year,

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'
```

Comment: set `DEBUG=True` and you will see what your problem is ... (you can also see the error in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (assuming you are serving it with apache)

Comment: I am not using apache I'm developing in visual studio

Comment: You should have `DEBUG=True` if you're just running on your local machine - makes troubleshooting much easier. You will get a full traceback of the problem.

Comment: then follow the other advice ... I would assume you would see the traceback in your terminal output though ... (also pycharm is much nicer (especially for django devel(although maybe those features are only in the paid version))

Comment: maybe I should switch to pycharm. was used to asp.net in visual studio but its been headaches all day with the autogenerated and outdated code

Comment: I second the PyCharm recommendation. That being said, once you have a traceback, edit your post to include it so we can see where the problem is stemming from.

Comment: the problem is that visual studio does offer a lot of premade templates similar to asp.net which I like a lot. I'll  post the traceback. I'm conflicted now. I'd have to write a lot more of my own code because the about page, index pages, login pages are all generated in visual studio. as well as models and views.py and bootstrap is there etc.

Comment: Thanks, much easier to figure out where to look first with the traceback :)

Answer (score 0):

For `render()`, you can pass context as a plain dictionary. If you're going to use a keyword argument, use `context` not `context_instance` [(docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render). That's why you're getting `render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context_instance'`:

```
def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""

    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(request, 'app/index.html', context={'title':'Home Page', 'year':datetime.now().year})
```